# why the code is showing module not found?

Tags: firebase

```
       import firebase from 'firebase'
    
     firebase.initializeApp({
        ..
    })

export default firebase
```

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'C:\Users\shravan\Documents\MERN stack\Courier App\client\src\component

Even after installing firebase why it is showing so?

Comment: Have you tried following the steps in `Use Firebase in your app` described in [firebase - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase)?

Comment: @CarlosMenezes yes i have, package is also showing firebase